# Access files stored on server with Tomcat webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, tomcat

I currently have a GWT webapp running on an Ubuntu 11.04 server with Tomcat6.  The app needs to be able to read and write to files from a specific folder on the server.  When running the app in dev mode through Eclipse (using the built in jetty instance, I suppose), it works fine. However, when I deploy the app to the Tomcat server, the app is unable to read/write the files.

What's the proper path structure to point to the correct folder on the server?  I.e. how would I tell the app to access the /home/username/project folder?

Is there a configuration setting that I need to make for Tomcat to allow accessing files?

Here's how I'm currently retrieving the file (where String file = "./projects/filename"):

```
public Project getProjectFromFile(String file) {
    Project p = null;
    try {       
        InputStream fis = getResourceAsStream(file);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            p = (Project) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("getProjectFromFile FileNotFoundException: "
                + e.getMessage());          
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        System.err.println("getProjectFromFile IOException: " + e.getMessage());        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
        System.err.println("getProjectFromFile ClassNotFoundException: " 
                + e.getMessage());          
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        System.err.println("getProjectFromFile Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return p;
}
```

I'm also open to suggestions to any suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to write to the home folder of the same user that's running the instance of Tomcat? That's usually the best method.

Comment: does the user that tomcat is running under have write/write access to the path tomcat is trying to read/write to?

Comment: I installed tomcat via apt-get, so the user is whatever the default is (root?) I set the folder permissions to 777 for now, just to get it working.  Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.  @Dave - not app engine, just home server for now

Comment: @Joni, see my answer about putting the files you're trying to access into your war directory and then using relative paths to load them.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the directories you want to be editable are owned by the same user that you are using to start Apache-Tomcat (through catalina.sh I assume) and permissions are set appropriately on those directories.

Comment: tomcat starts automatically when on server boot.  i haven't changed any tomcat settings since installing it via apt-get.  how can i tell which user is running it?

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you're working with servlets, it is always best to use relative paths and put whatever files you're trying to load (xml, png, html, css, etc) somewhere within your war directory.

Once you've done this, you should just be able to use the relative path of the file.  For example, to load `/home/path/to/your/eclipse/project/war/html/view/a_random_page.html` in your code, you simply use `./html/view/a_random_page.html` as your file path when you're trying to load it.

The reason for this is because these files are packaged with your project, so when you deploy it, you don't also have to worry about copying the files you want to use to the web server separate from deployment.

Doing things this way helps make it much easier to deploy as well as move your installation into different directories/web servers.  It also makes it easier if you ever have to have more than one person working on the project with you.  Going about it the way you currently are, if anyone started to help you on the project then you would have to both change all of the absolute paths to point to the proper files on your respective machines.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and placed the files in a folder in the war directory as such.  This works fine when running in eclipse, but I get the same results once the war is deployed on the server.

Comment: please see my edited question above, which now includes some sample code.

Comment: How are you deploying?  Are you dropping the war onto the web server?

Comment: I'm using the server's tomcat-manager to upload and deploy the war

Comment: I've never used that - but open up the war file and see if the files are where you think they are.  Could be something in the way you're building...

Comment: Did as you suggested.  The files are in place as expected.

Comment: This won't work if he's trying to read/write files. The resources included in the war are loaded at deployment, and not updated during runtime

Comment: Very true, but just because the OP is able to write to the disk it doesn't mean the OP should be.  Writing to files on the disk makes using absolute paths makes it more difficult to deploy the server.  It may work ok for a small web app where the same person who is working on the web app is deploying, but in larger applications or internal web applications (where the people writing the app have no control over how it is deployed) it is a consistent point of low quality and internal exceptions when you rely on hard coded file to exist.  It is possible, but shouldn't be encouraged.